# Extract .xsn extension files using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is it possible to extract `.xsn` extension file in Node.JS 
I am using electron to convert InfoPath forms into html templates, but I got stuck at phase one.

I tried using extract-zip, ZipJS libraries, but their mainly focused on ZIP files. Renaming the `.xsn` extension to `.zip` did not solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

The Infopath `*.xsn` files are cabinet files (CAB). An archived MSDN blog post has a script but that depends on the `extract.exe` utility and thus requires windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/infopath/modifying-infopath-manifest-xsf-file-from-script-25

Comment: thanks for the reply, i made it work using powershell module node-powershell, but i guess it will only work on windows now.